# Is it possible to restrict UDP packets being sent to an FPGA to a single host?

Tags: qt, udp, fpga

I'm trying to send data from a Qt application on a Windows 11 PC to an Arty A7-100T equipped with the Xilinx TEMAC IP Core.

Currently the Qt app just consists of a start/stop toggle button that, when pressed, sends a byte of data to the FPGA. If the byte is a specific number, one of the onboard LEDs toggles.

This works in that pressing the button on the Qt GUI will toggle the LED state, but sometimes the LED will toggle without me clicking anything, meaning that supposedly there's something else on my PC that is sending data to the FPGA. This happens regardless of whether I have the Qt application running or not, but it does not happen if I unplug the ethernet from the FPGA.

I thought that the `QAbstractSocket::bind` command with `bindMode` set to `DontShareAddress` would stop other services from communicating with the FPGA, but I guess that isn't the case.

What I can do to ensure the only thing sending data to the FPGA is my Qt application?

Comment: Maybe you have made a poor choice of UDP port for the FPGA to receive on.  If it is the same port used by some well-known service, then it is plausible that something either on your computer or on another connected to the same network is generating those extra packets, trying to communicate with an instance of that service.  They might not even be communicating *specifically* with your FPGA: it is plausible that they are sending out UDP broadcasts on your network.

Comment: There are other, more sinister possibilities, too.  For example, maybe there is a port scanner running somewhere on your network.

Comment: That's fair. I chose a port in the 49152 – 65535 range hoping that I wouldn't run into an issue like that, but I'll try out some other ports. I will mention that I'm on a university private network.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "university private network" is, but if you mean an internal network operated by a university, then there are likely many other machines on it, too.  Such networks tend to be fairly noisy, and it's not uncommon for there to be various kinds of weird things running on them.  Port scanners are not unlikely, perhaps including some operated by the university itself.  If you need to ensure that nothing but your PC ever sends packets to the FPGA then you probably need to isolate these on their own, genuinely private, network.

Comment: So in pursuit of verifying whether my network was the issue or not, I disconnected my network connection to see if the problem would go away. The LED toggled much less frequently when not connected to the network, but it didn't completely fix the issue. The LED still toggled every once in a while. That leads me to believe that something else on my PC is sending data to the FPGA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible in the way that you mean, no. You can control the channel it listens on (which in this case is the port) but you cannot control who speaks on that port. You could try to find an empty port, as you have, but as you've discovered, there's no way to guarantee that no one else is talking on that port.

What you could do is create a protocol that only your FPGA and Qt app are privy to.

For example, you could hardcode a "password" on both ends. Lets say you decide to make it 7 digits, and the password is 1111111. Then the Qt app could send 8 bytes, with the first 7 being all 1's and the last being your specific number to activate the LEDs. Your FPGA would store each byte into a FIFO buffer of size 8 bytes. Then it would compare the first 7 against the password; if they are all 1's, then it could check if the last byte is that specific number and toggle the LEDs.

This is why we have protocols and encryption; on any network, from a LAN to your University "private" network to the entire internet, no listener can know who it is that's speaking. And similarly, no speaker can know who's listening. Even when you unplugged your network cable, you still found that some other process is occasionally transmitting on that port. The only way to absolutely ensure only a single host is talking to your FPGA is to create a network containing only your FPGA and your desired host.

Comment: Choosing this as the answer as it answers the original question of whether you can isolate listening to a single host while also providing a method to work past the issue. My plan was to implement a header/data section (as described further by @Im Groot), but I just hadn't gotten that far yet and became concerned about the extra data that seemed to be coming in.

Comment: It's important to note that a byte has 8 bits and so 2^8 = 256 possible values. And processes tend to send out flurries of bytes. So the odds become quite good that at some point that byte would be sent by something. You could probabilistically reduce the incidence of these false positives by using a signature composed of more than a single byte =)

Answer (score 1):

Sending only one byte of data and then implementing some functionality on that is a poor approach. A very common practice is to split your ethernet packet into `header` and `data` section.

`header` will help you identify that it is a correct packet i.e. the source is trusted and the format of packet is what you decided. After verifying the `header`, you can use the `data` to implement your functionality. Here is a basic packet structure in C:

```c
//Header:
UDP_packet[0] = 0x10EE9011; //Header start
UDP_packet[1] = 1;          //Packet number

//Data:
UDP_packet[2] = 0x00000074; // Your 1 byte of data
```

`Packet number` is a counter that is incremented for every packet. This is implemented to detect packet drop.